# How can I allow a VirtualBox machine to reach the internet but bot LAN devices?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I need to setup a VirtualBox machine that:

1. can connect to the internet;
2. can't connect to the devices in my LAN.

If I understand the [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes), I should reate a [NAT Network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service) from `File > Preferences > Network` and then set `Settings > Network > Adapter 1` to:

- `[✓] Enable Network Adapter`
- `Attached to: [NAT Network ▼]`
- `Name: [NatNetwork ▼]`

However, if I do so my virtual machine is still able to reach my modem, the host system and any other device in the LAN.

Is my setup hypothesis correct? If not, what I'm missing?

---

### Update: some more info

#### Host

- Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS
- root permissions available
- WiFi connected
- ethernet hardware available and working but not usable (because of the position of the PC)

#### Guest

- Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

If other info are needed, please ask for them.

Comment: This is a complex question: It gets into multiple routes, VLANs, and Subnets. Setting it up is not trivial, and it will require you to do some extensive work with your router and VM Host (not the VN Guest). Please edit your question to describe your VM Host OS and the host machine's wired and wireless network interfaces

Comment: @user535733 I added some possibly relevant info, but I don't know what might be necessary. If the answer requires other details please tell me what they are exactly so that I can provide them - I'm "quite" a newbie about the subject.

Comment: Wifi-only makes the problem simpler: You cannot do it most of the complex ways. Most Wifi hardware can associate with only a single MAC address. You are stuck with NAT, which means that preventing the Guest from reaching anything else on your LAN also means preventing the Host from reaching anything else on your LAN. This makes it a general-networking question, not Ubuntu-specific. Have your router/wifi-access-point create new subnet. Use one subnet for the VM Host, another subnet for the LAN, and disallow communication between the two subnets.